# Jython - Do these two boolean statements do the same thing?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm reasonably new to Python but I *thought* I understood how the flow control worked.

I'm pasting this from the [Jython github](https://github.com/jython/jython/blob/0a58cc26566d2b2334e80b2b3f2f42f6c738db2d/lib-python/2.7/ihooks.py) at line 418

```
418: pkgname = globals.get('__package__')
419: if pkgname is not None:
420:     if not pkgname and level > 0:
421:         raise ValueError, 'Attempted relative import in non-package'
```

Does `pkgname is not None` on line 419 do the same thing as `not pkgname` on line 420? If it does, why would that check be there?

I'm reading the import source code so I can understand the system better and, though minor, this struck me as odd. As I'm still learning Python, I don't want to take anything for granted.

Thank you!

Comment: They're not exactly the same.  `not pkgname` checks for any false-like value such as 0, blank string, `False`, etc, but `is not None` checks for precisely the value `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the valid values are for `pkgname` but technically `not pkgname` could test for any *falsy* value, such as `None`, but also `False`, `0`, `[]`, `""` etc. However, `globals.get()` will only return `None` if the `globals()` dict key is absent so if the intention is only to test for that then it is indeed redundant.

Side note: wonder why you're learning python via reading the Jython codebase. I suggest you start with using the reference CPython implementation and with the docs rather than the codebase itself

Comment: I'm using Java as a GUI and Python as an in-game scripting language. I'm learning Python as I write the in-game code. I'm reading the Jython codebase because Jython is giving me trouble and no one seems to be able to respond to my queries. Figured I'd look into the source to see what might be up.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the second check for if not pkgname is not needed so the code can just be

```py
418: pkgname = globals.get('__package__')
419: if pkgname is not None:
420:     if level > 0:
421:         raise ValueError, 'Attempted relative import in non-package'
```

Comment: Your answer is ALSO correct but Chris_Rands was more thorough. Thank you